# XLPagerTabStrip: Dynamically adding subviews to tab's view controllers wouldn't display except under first tab

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

XLPagerTabStrip: Dynamically adding subviews to tab's view controllers wouldn't display except under first tab.

Please download the project and run it to see the problem:

https://github.com/farhan101/TheProblemView

**First Tab:** Under View One tab you can see a spinner added dynamically

[image: First Tab]

**Second Tab:** Under View Two tab same spinner is added but it wouldn't show
[image: Second Tab]

PS: As you can see in the source code, both view controllers are instances of the same view controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the parent `view'`s `bounds` instead of `frame` while creating `ViewToAdd`.

```
let vu = ViewToAdd(frame: self.view.bounds, yFactor: 2.0)
```